# Pandas EWMA not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate EWMA using pandas, but the result is not what I expected. I think the 4th element should be 13.179 but pandas gives 13.121. I converted the decay factor(a) to center of mass by the formula specified in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html). Am I misunderstanding anything?

```
In[222]: y
Out[222]: 
0          NaN
1          NaN
2    13.192161
3    13.109292
4    12.623850
5    12.150520
Name: data, dtype: float64

In[223]: pd.ewma(y, com = 1.0 / a - 1)
Out[223]: 
0          NaN
1          NaN
2    13.192161
3    13.120667
4    12.701206
5    12.237839
dtype: float64

In[224]: a
Out[224]: 0.8408964152537145

In[225]: a * 13.192161 + (1 - a) * 13.109292
Out[225]: 13.17897624503566
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the docs say

```
a = com/(1 + com)
```

it follows that

```
com = a/(1.0-a)
```

(for 0 <= a < 1).

---

Also, there is an adjustment made to the values computed during the beginning periods ["to account for imbalance in relative weightings"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html#:%7E:text=to%20account%20for%20imbalance%20in%20relative%20weightings).
To confirm the formula

[image]

let's turn off that adjustment:

```
z = pd.ewma(x, com=a/(1.0-a), adjust=False)
print(z)
```

then prints

```
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    2.098920
3    3.850710
4    5.246548
5    6.344995
```

and this result can be mimicked by computing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.testing.utils as NTU

nan = np.nan
x = pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, 13.109292, 12.623850, 12.150520])
a = 0.8408964152537145
z = pd.ewma(x, com=a/(1.0-a), adjust=False)

def nanzero(x):
    return 0 if np.isnan(x) else x

x.ffill(inplace=True)
y = [x[0]]
for xt in x[1:]:
    yt1 = y[-1]
    if np.isnan(yt1) and np.isnan(xt):
        yt = nan
    else:
        yt1 = nanzero(yt1)
        xt = nanzero(xt)
        yt = a*yt1 + (1-a)*xt
        # yt = (1-a)*yt1 + a*xt
    y.append(yt)
y = pd.Series(y)

NTU.assert_allclose(y,z)
```

Comment: It looks like there is a typo. In the documentation provided by my link, it says a = 1 / (c + 1). Thanks.

Comment: this is the proposed doc fix (from a while back)..... can one of you guys comment if this looks correct? thanks: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4321

Comment: @Jeff: I haven't studied the C code defining ewma, so the code above probably does not replicate ewma perfectly, but it does seem to show that for at least some simple cases `yt = a*yt1 + (1-a)*xt` is the correct formula. I've left a comment stating this [on the github page](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4321).

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, in my opinion they are.